# Сортировка массива в PHP по заданной последовательности

Tags: php

Всем доброго дня.

Подскажите как сделать сортировку массива?

Вот например такой исходный массив:

```
array(
    0=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>'abc'),
    1=>array('a'=>3,'b'=>'bca'),
    2=>array('a'=>3,'b'=>'cab'),
    3=>array('a'=>4,'b'=>'abb'),
    4=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'cbc')
)
```

Мне нужно отсортировать его по значению поля 'a', но порядок сортировки я хочу задать другим массивом, например:

```
array(4,2,1,3)
```

Буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, написал кое-что. Идея в том, чтобы проходим второй массив, и в наш массив берем подходящие элементы.

```
function MySort($arr, $sa)
{
    $retArr = array();
    $c = count($arr);

    foreach ($sa as $k => $v)
    {
        for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
        {
            if ($arr[$i]['a'] == $v)
                $retArr[] = $arr[$i];
        }
    }

    return $retArr;
}
```

**Пример вызова:**

```
$z = array(
    0=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>'abc'),
    1=>array('a'=>3,'b'=>'bca'),
    2=>array('a'=>3,'b'=>'cab'),
    3=>array('a'=>4,'b'=>'abb'),
    4=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'cbc')
);

$a = array(4,2,1,3);

print_r(MySort($z, $a));
```

Comment: То, что доктор прописал! Спасибо!

Answer (score 7):

Без велосипеда:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($sort) {
    $sort = array_flip($sort);

    return $sort[$a['a']] > $sort[$b['a']];
});
```

Минимальные требования: PHP >= 5.3

Comment: Спасибо, отличное решение! Перепринимать ответ не буду (некрасиво), подкинул очков уважухи!

Comment: отлично, я тоже немного научился ))) А то вечно велосипеды придумываю :)

Comment: :) рад, что помог обоим