# Сортировка двумерного массива по другому массиву

Tags: массивы, php

Всем доброго времени суток!

Голова уже кипит, не знаю в чем проблема.

Есть массив `$mas_emp`:

```
Array
  {

    [0]=>Array
        {
           [number]=>
           [Name]=>
           [Position]=>
         }
   }
```

Так же есть массив позиций:

```
$type_emp_sort = array("Supervisor","Line leader","Relief","Materialist","Repairman")
```

Сопсна вопрос... **КАК** отсортировать первый массив так, что бы первыми шли работники, у которых поле `Position` = `Supervisor`, за ними `Line leader` и т.д.

Пробовал  `array_multisort`(`$mas_emp`,`$type_emp_sort`) ( и `array_multisort`(`$type_emp_sort`,`$mas_emp`) ) . Не помогает. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь!

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая, искали бы на сайте сначала: [вчерашний вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/209150/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-php-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/209150#209154) есть ответ, как отсортировать.

**p.s.** С помощью **usort**

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($sort) {
    $sort = array_flip($sort);

    return $sort[$a['a']] > $sort[$b['a']];
});
```

Минимальные требования: PHP >= 5.3